# "user is not associated to feed!" sequelizejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

For some reason he is not finding the association. And I created the association and the foreign key is creating perfectly in postgres.

user.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = app => {
    const sequelize = app.db_connect.postgres.connect;
    const Sequelize = app.db_connect.postgres.require;
    const Reputation = app.models.reputation;
    const Report = app.models.report;
    const Group = app.models.group;
    const Participant = app.models.participant;
    const Topic = app.models.topic;
    const Feed = app.models.feed;

    const User = sequelize.define('user', {
        //atributes
    });

    User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'User', through: 'relationship', foreignKey: 'userId' });
    User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'Following', through: 'relationship', foreignKey: 'followingId' });
    User.belongsToMany(Group, { as: 'Member', through: Participant, foreignKey: 'userId' });
    User.hasMany(Report);
    User.hasMany(Topic);
    User.hasMany(Feed); //associate


    return User;
}
```

feed.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = app => {
    const sequelize = app.db_connect.postgres.connect;
    const Sequelize = app.db_connect.postgres.require;
    const Report = app.models.report;

    const Feed = sequelize.define('feed', {
        //atributes
    });

    Feed.hasMany(Feed, {as: 'father'});
    Feed.hasMany(Report)

    return Feed;
}
```

call:

```
    const User = app.models.user;
    const Sequelize = app.db_connect.postgres.require;

    Feed.findOne({
        include: User,
        where: {
            id: req.params.id
        }
    })
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(412).json({msg: error.message});
    });
```

user and feed has a associate of 1:n. So I used the hasMany sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're querying Feed, not User, you need to define that "other side" (inverse) of the association as well:

```
Feed.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'User',
  foreignKey: 'UserID' // or whatever your fk column is named for Feed -> User
});
```

Note that when you call Feed.findOne, you usually need to pass the same `as` value as the one you set on the association:

```
Feed.findOne({
  include: {
    model: User,
    as: 'User' // must match the "as" from the defined association above
  },
  where: {
    id: req.params.id
  }
});
```